# Typescript / ESLint rule for referencing an invalid property

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I'm looking for an ESLint rule that will prevent me from referencing an invalid object property.

Given:

```
const foo = {
  "bar-loo": 1,
  "gar-zoo": "something goes here"
}
```

Good:

```
const x = foo["bar-loo"];
```

Bad:

```
const x = foo["bar-zoo"];
```

Just really looking for a way to make ESLint complain when I do the "Bad" example.

I've tried digging around the docs but the closest I can find is [this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-computed-key#disallow-unnecessary-computed-property-keys-in-objects-and-classes-no-useless-computed-key) and it doesn't really fit what I want to do.

Or if there's any way I can do this with as typescript config, that'd be great too!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your Bad example throws an error for me already. `Property 'bar-zoo' does not exist on type '{ "bar-loo": number; "gar-zoo": string; }'. Did you mean 'bar-loo'?(2551)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/W44XeW).  Possibly you are not using the `--noImplicitAny` or the `--strict` compiler options (and if you're not, you should).  Or you have some other problem with your environment that I couldn't hope to guess.  Please consider producing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you're talking about.

Comment: d'oh! i feel so stupid. I had strict turned off all along. :/ My bad, thanks guys!